# Meteor: jQuery is not defined

Tags: meteor

I am having a problem with using jQuery in my Meteor app. It is undefined.

When I look inside `.meteor/versions`, I can clearly see:

```
jquery@1.11.3_2
```

But when I type `$` or `jQuery` in my Chrome console, I get `undefined`. Also, I cannot use external packages that use any jQuery; I get `undefined is not a function` exception.

Manually adding jQuery package by `meteor add jquery` did not solve the issue.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is inside the meteor core and defined as a dependency inside [meteor-platform](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor-platform/package.js). So I never declare it as a a dependency. Meteor relies heavily on it, so it's unlikely to ever be removed. Unlike underscore, which they stated they will remove in a future release. Meteor always aliases `$`. So that should work. It can't be an issue with that specific version. I'm running the same without any issues. Here are some things you could try to debug:

- Create a new project and check if JQ works
- Check if an installed package is causing the problem (by removing them one by one)

Packages get loaded before your code, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I debugged by commenting out various file contents. It turns out that MailChimp script was using `jQuery.noConflict(true)` and removing `$` from the global namespace. Resolved it by removing `noConflict(true)`, but don't know why they were using it in the first place.